# Как отслеживать программное изменение select средствами js/jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть обычный  тэг select.
Есть замечательное событие change, которое прекрасно работает, когда пользователь вручную меняет значение этого селекта.
Есть строка $("select").val(someValue), которая совершенно замечательно меняет значение селекта, но при этом событие change не возникает.
В силу ряда обстоятельств нельзя диктовать, чтобы изменение значения селекта задавалось каким-либо нестандартным способом.
Так возник вопрос: как отследить программное изменение селекта?

Comment: Вы бы что ли обратили внимание на то, что ответ уже принят.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А я покажу вам особую, уличную магию :)

```
jQuery.fn.val1 = jQuery.fn.val;
jQuery.fn.val = function() {
  var el = $(this),
    val = jQuery.fn.val1.apply(el, arguments);
  if (el.is('select') && arguments.length == 1)
    el.trigger('change');
  return val;
}
```

[пруф](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test48.php)

**Ахтунг!**

1. автор не несет ответственности за потерянные при понимании и отладке нервные клетки
2. это набор грязных, пошлых хаков (минимум 3)
3. это нечто работает только в ситуации вопроса, за любое другое применение автор тоже ответственности не несет (но при необходимости и по приколу может дописать)

**UPD** Привел к понятному виду, минус 2 хака. Но тот вариант был веселее.

Comment: Спасибо! Насколько всё просто :)

Comment: Я не в курсе, это "несрабатываение" только ли к select относится? Если нет, можно убрать проверку на select и получить "универсальную" функцию

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях после изменения программным способом я просто явно вызываю это событие.

```
$('select').val(42).trigger('change');
```

Главное убедиться, что аргумент `.val()` существует, иначе `.val(undefined)` вернет нам не `jquery` объект, а его значение, и получим исключение.

Манкипатчинг это, конечно же, вариант, но по мне так более явно.

Comment: спасибо. Но это не всегда правильно.

Comment: Неправильно - почему? Когда значение `select` меняет неподконтрольный вам код?